# How to work out orders my Stock came from?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
Item Number, QTY on Hand
```

Table 2:

```
Item Number, Description, Received Number, QTY Received, Received Date
```

What I need to do is find out a way to show which received orders my stock on hand came from.

Example: Item 12345 I have 300 on hand.

I have received multiple orders

```
Order 1 - 100
order 2 - 100
Order 3 - 50
Order 4 - 100
Order x - x
etc
```

I am assuming first in first out logic. So what I would want to see is

```
Item 12345 - SOH 300
```

and these are the orders it came from:

```
Order 1 - 100
order 2 - 100
Order 3 - 50
Order 4 - 50
```

At the end of the day I want to see something like this:

![hopeful end result][1]

**Attempts**

```sql
-- Table 1  
select ITEMNO, QTYONHAND 
from iciloc 
where QTYONHAND <> 0 
and LOCATION = 'M'  

-- Table 2  
SELECT PORCPH1.RCPNUMBER, PORCPH1.DATE, PORCPL.ITEMNO, PORCPL.ITEMDESC, PORCPL.RQRECEIVED 
FROM PORCPL 
INNER JOIN PORCPH1 ON PORCPL.RCPHSEQ = PORCPH1.RCPHSEQ 
where PORCPL.ITEMNO in (
  select ITEMNO from iciloc where QTYONHAND <> 0 and LOCATION = 'M'
) 
AND PORCPH1.DATE <= 20100101 
order by ITEMNO
```

---

Hello Ravioli,

i have played around with your code and made a changed to match my tables and it looks like some of the skus work and some dont example :

```
SELECT ICILOC.ITEMNO, PORCPL.RCPHSEQ, PORCPL.RQRECEIVED, PORCPH1.RCPNUMBER, PORCPH1.DATE
FROM ICILOC
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    PORCPL.ITEMNO, 
    PORCPL.RCPHSEQ,
    PORCPL.RQRECEIVED,
    PORCPL.DTARRIVAL,
    SUM(PORCPL.RQRECEIVED) OVER(
      PARTITION BY PORCPL.ITEMNO -- Calculate inventory per item
      ORDER BY PORCPL.DTARRIVAL DESC -- Order by most recently received
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING -- Cumulative sum, exc. current row
    ) AS CSUM_latest
  FROM PORCPL
) PORCPL ON PORCPL.ITEMNO = ICILOC.ITEMNO -- Get order info
LEFT JOIN PORCPH1 ON PORCPL.RCPHSEQ = PORCPH1.RCPHSEQ
WHERE COALESCE(PORCPL.CSUM_latest, 0) < ICILOC.QTYONHAND -- Only get enough orders to cover SOH
ORDER BY ICILOC.ITEMNO, PORCPL.RCPHSEQ
```

After running this query i get the following result as an example :

![Query 1][2]

Stock on hand:

![SOH][3]

As you can see with PN 1 it should only show receipt 3 as it has 280,000 and SOH is 266,400

This is my ideal outcome:

So it only shows the receipts that equal the current SOH

![result i am aiming for][4]

---

---

I have done a little bit of tweaking to the following

```
SELECT distinct ICILOC.ITEMNO, PORCPL.RCPHSEQ, PORCPL.RQRECEIVED, PORCPH1.RCPNUMBER, PORCPH1.DATE
FROM ICILOC
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    PORCPL.ITEMNO, 
    PORCPL.RCPHSEQ,
    PORCPL.RQRECEIVED,
    PORCPL.DTARRIVAL,
    SUM(PORCPL.RQRECEIVED) OVER(
      PARTITION BY PORCPL.ITEMNO -- Calculate inventory per item
      ORDER BY PORCPL.DTARRIVAL DESC -- Order by most recently received
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING -- Cumulative sum, exc. current row
    ) AS CSUM_latest
  FROM PORCPL
) PORCPL ON PORCPL.ITEMNO = ICILOC.ITEMNO -- Get order info
LEFT JOIN PORCPH1 ON PORCPL.RCPHSEQ = PORCPH1.RCPHSEQ
WHERE COALESCE(PORCPL.CSUM_latest, 0) < ICILOC.QTYONHAND -- Only get enough orders to cover SOH
ORDER BY ICILOC.ITEMNO, PORCPL.RCPHSEQ
```

my only thing i need to fix now it the oldest receipt / order i do not want this to show the whole order i just want it to show many many from this are left

example

so by order one / two / three i mean:

01.01.2018 i ordered 100 from the factory (order 1)
01.02.2018 i ordered 20 from the factory (order 2)
01.03.2018 i ordered 25 from the factory (order 3)

Currently I have 50 on hand.  So what I can assume is:

- the 95 from order 1 has been sold
- we still have 5 left from order 1
- we still have the 20 from order 2
- we still have the 25 from order 3

assuming the warehouse does First in First out

which we are assuming they are

hopefully this makes sense

---

***Hello @ravioli,**
please see bellow as requested:
here is my current SOH

```
PN1  48,977 
PN2  44,206 
PN3  14,020
```

This is what i am getting when i run the current code :

```
ItemCode    Recipt  Date         received
PN1         RCP1    10/09/2019   25,600 
PN1         RCP2    12/09/2019   25,600 
PN2         RCP3    26/07/2019   21,600 
PN2         RCP4    24/09/2019   36,000 
PN3         RCP5    30/04/2019   7,200 
PN3         RCP6    24/09/2019   7,200
```

this what what i would like to see

```
ItemCode    Recipt  Date         received
PN1         RCP1    10/09/2019   23,377 
PN1         RCP2    12/09/2019   22,606 
PN2         RCP3    26/07/2019   21,600 
PN2         RCP4    24/09/2019   36,000 
PN3         RCP5    30/04/2019   6,820 
PN3         RCP6    24/09/2019   7,200
```

So instead of the oldest receipt showing the full "received" it should only show what is needed to = the current SOH

**______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________**

Hey All just and updated i have added 3 skus into [sqlfiddle][5]

Here is my SOH

```
| ITEMNO | QTYONHAND |
|--------|-----------|
|      1 |    266400 |
|      2 |     19190 |
|      3 |      4025 |
```

Here is the output i get

```
| ITEMNO | RCPNUMBER |  DTARRIVAL | RQRECEIVED |
|--------|-----------|------------|------------|
|      1 |         3 | 2019-09-24 |     280000 |
|      2 |         4 | 2019-03-20 |       7200 |
|      2 |         5 | 2019-09-10 |       7200 |
|      2 |         6 | 2019-09-24 |       7200 |
|      3 |         7 | 2018-06-27 |      14700 |
|      3 |         8 | 2018-07-06 |       1000 |
|      3 |         9 | 2018-07-06 |       2000 |
```

---

Here is what i would like to see :

```
| ITEMNO | RCPNUMBER |  DTARRIVAL | RQRECEIVED |
|--------|-----------|------------|------------|
|      1 |         3 | 2019-09-24 |     266400 |
|      2 |         4 | 2019-03-20 |       4790 |
|      2 |         5 | 2019-09-10 |       7200 |
|      2 |         6 | 2019-09-24 |       7200 |
|      3 |         7 | 2018-06-27 |       1025 |
|      3 |         8 | 2018-07-06 |       1000 |
|      3 |         9 | 2018-07-06 |       2000 |
________________________________________________
```

So what i would like to have is for example

ITEMNO 3 SOH is 4,025 the stock on hand has come through on three RCPNUMBER

7 - 14,700

8 - 1,000

9 - 2,000

instead of seeing all three i just want to the QTYs that will add up to the SOH
On this occasion its the full order 9 + the full Order 8 + 1,025 only from Order 7

so 2,000 (order 9) + 1,000 (order 8) + 1,025 (part of order 7) = 4,025 (current SOH)
**______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________**

**current code i am happy with**

````
SELECT DISTINCT ICILOC.ITEMNO,PORCPL.ITEMDESC,PORCPH1.RCPNUMBER, PORCPL.RQRECEIVED, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(30),PORCPH1.DATE), 103) as DATE, QTYONHAND,
  CASE 
    WHEN (COALESCE(CSUM_Latest,0) + PORCPL.RQRECEIVED) > QTYONHAND -- Partial order needed for SOH
      THEN (COALESCE(CSUM_Latest,0) + PORCPL.RQRECEIVED) - QTYONHAND -- Diff. of cum. QTYRec and SOH
    ELSE PORCPL.RQRECEIVED 
  END AS QTYReceived_SOH
  ,PG1_Desc,PG2_Desc,PG3_Desc,PG4_Desc, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(30),GETDATE()), 103) - CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(30),PORCPH1.DATE), 103) as AGE,TOTALCOST/QTYONHAND as AVGCOST,
    CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(30),PORCPH1.DATE), 103) > CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(30),GETDATE()-365), 103) 
      THEN 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
  END AS OLDER_THAN_12_MONTHS
    FROM ICILOC
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    PORCPL.ITEMNO, 
    PORCPL.RCPHSEQ,
    PORCPL.RQRECEIVED,
    PORCPL.DTARRIVAL,
    PORCPL.ITEMDESC,
    SUM(PORCPL.RQRECEIVED) OVER(
      PARTITION BY PORCPL.ITEMNO -- Calculate inventory per item
      ORDER BY PORCPL.DTARRIVAL DESC -- Order by most recently received
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING -- Cumulative sum, exc. current row
    ) AS CSUM_latest
  FROM PORCPL
) PORCPL ON PORCPL.ITEMNO = ICILOC.ITEMNO -- Get order info
LEFT JOIN PORCPH1 ON PORCPL.RCPHSEQ = PORCPH1.RCPHSEQ
LEFT JOIN Datawarehouse.dbo.Item_Details ON Item_Details.ItemCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = ICILOC.ITEMNO COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    WHERE COALESCE(PORCPL.CSUM_latest, 0) < ICILOC.QTYONHAND and LOCATION = 'M'  -- Only get enough orders to cover SOH
        ORDER BY ICILOC.ITEMNO, PORCPH1.RCPNUMBER;```








  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WubWp.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5lDe.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOwMn.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyXiL.png
  [5]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/275dad/20
````

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: And if you could show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. **[edit]** your question instead

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```sql
SELECT items.ItemNumber, orders.ReceivedNumber, orders.QTYReceived
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    ItemNumber, 
    ReceivedNumber,
    QTYReceived,
    SUM(QTYReceived) OVER(
      PARTITION BY ItemNumber -- Calculate inventory per item
      ORDER BY ReceivedDate DESC -- Order by most recently received
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING -- Cumulative sum, exc. current row
    ) AS CSUM_latest
  FROM Orders
) orders ON orders.ItemNumber = items.ItemNumber -- Get order info
WHERE COALESCE(orders.CSUM_latest, 0) < items.SOH -- Only get enough orders to cover SOH
ORDER BY items.ItemNumber, orders.ReceivedNumber
```

The table / column names are based on the description you provided, not the actual SQL / DDL.  You'll need to adjust it to fit your actual model.  Give it a try and let me know how it goes.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ccaf9/17)

**Update**
I added a new field `QTYReceived_SOH` with logic to return the partial value of the last order that completes the current `SOH`:

```sql
SELECT 
  items.ItemNumber, orders.ReceivedNumber, orders.QTYReceived,
  CASE 
    WHEN (COALESCE(CSUM_Latest,0) + QTYReceived) > SOH -- Partial order needed for SOH
      THEN (COALESCE(CSUM_Latest,0) + QTYReceived) - SOH -- Diff. of cum. QTYRec and SOH
    ELSE orders.QTYReceived 
  END AS QTYReceived_SOH,
  CSUM_Latest
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    ItemNumber, 
    ReceivedNumber,
    QTYReceived,
    SUM(QTYReceived) OVER(
      PARTITION BY ItemNumber -- Calculate inventory per item
      ORDER BY ReceivedDate DESC-- Order by most recently received
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING -- Cum. count (exc. current row)
    ) AS CSUM_latest
  FROM Orders
) orders ON orders.ItemNumber = items.ItemNumber -- get order info for each item
WHERE COALESCE(orders.CSUM_latest,0) < items.SOH -- Get enough orders to cover SOH
ORDER BY items.ItemNumber, orders.ReceivedNumber DESC
```

Try adapting that to your query and let me know.

[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ccaf9/43)

Comment: Hello @ravioli thanks for this
i have added what i have done and the result i have gotten 
i really appreciate  your help :)

Comment: You're welcome.  I can't access images from where I am.  Any chance you can post the sample output (`query` and `result i am aiming for`) as text?

Comment: hello @ravioli i have edited and shown what you are requesting to see :)

Comment: i have also edited the photos so it should show without needing to use the link etc :)

Comment: Thanks.  Your `what i am getting when i run the current code` (`ItemCode, Recipt, Date, received`) doesn't match the "tweaked" query you included.  Does that actually represent the `Table 1` data?

Comment: I think I understand what you want.  For the "last" order that constitutes the `SOH` (the one that is only partially depleted), you want to use `SOH` instead of the `RQReceived` associated with the order.  Is that correct?

Comment: for the "last" (oldest) order that is used i want it to only show the part quantity so when i add all the RQRecived it will equal my SOH

Comment: So pretty much the last order (oldest) should usally never be the full received qty as it should have stock used from it ... so the last receipt should be something like last recipt = (SOH minus recipt 1) minus receipts 2 so on pending on number of receipts...

Comment: OK...I updated my response.  Take a look and let me know.  By the way, I think this situation is better named LIFO - Last In First Out.  FIFO (First in First Out) as you called it, at least to me, implies that the first ones in (i.e. the oldest ones) are the first ones out.

Comment: Hi Ravioli, This works really well :) you are the best :D 
Just curious am i able to do a case based on the "QTYReceived_SOH" you created ?

What i want it to be is 
=IF(RQRECEIVED=QTYReceived_SOH,QTYReceived_SOH,RQRECEIVED-QTYReceived_SOH)

i have done this is a calculated field in my excel pivot just wondering can it be done in SQL

Comment: You're very welcome.  Yes, you can reference `QTYReceived_SOH` in a `CASE` statement like any other field, but you'd have to wrap the entire `SELECT` in another outer `SELECT` first.  In some DBMSs like Teradata, you wouldn't have to do this, but I think in SQL Server you need to.  You want something like `SELECT ItemNumber, ReceivedNumber, QTYReceived, QTYReceived_SOH, <field_using_QTYReceived_SOH> FROM (<updated_query_without_ORDER_BY>) src ORDER BY ...`